# Woocommerce - Is it possible to define a default value for products without a price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to define a default value that will be displayed such as "TBC" when a product has no price set.

I have tried a few different code snippets and none of them seem to give me the results im wanting.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can used `woocommerce_empty_price_html` filer hook for simple product .
For variable product used `woocommerce_variable_empty_price_html`. 
for variation product used `woocommerce_variation_empty_price_html`

Please try below code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_empty_price_html');
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_empty_price_html');
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_empty_price_html');
function custom_call_for_empty_price_html() {
     return 'TBC';
}
```

put this code in your active theme `function.php` file